# Error in Final Launch Sequence - Eclipse System Workbench Debugging for STM32L476

Tags: eclipse, system, stm32, workbench, openocd

I'm trying to debug and run simple assembly code for STM32L476. I've set up Eclipse Oxygen, installed the latest version of System Workbench plugin in Eclipse and installed ST-Link drivers. The IDE successfully builds the program without throwing any errors, however when I connect my STM Discovery Board and try to debug, the program throws the following error:

> Error in Final Launch Sequence - Reset Command not defined for device 'Generic TCP/IP'.

[image: Error Image 1], 
[image: Error Image 2]

I'm getting this error on both Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 having used the exact same software. Having read a few other posts regarding issues similar to this, I was told to check whether I've OpenOCD and arm-none-eabi-gdb setup within Eclipse, and they have been set up properly as show in the image below.

[image: Debugger Settings]

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when updating to the latest version of Eclipse. After doing some research I found a bug report on the bug tracker page of Eclipse:

> [Bug 529171 - Recent Pushed update causing - Reset Command not defined for device 'Generic TCP/IP'](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529171)

This states that the module causing the issue is *C/C++ GDB Hardware Debugging* version 9.4.0.201712051550. I verified it and I had the same version when the error occured. The current solution is to revert to a previous version. By reverting to version 9.3.2.201709131603 the issue is solved and I can use GDB to debug the STM microcontrollers.

You can find the current version of this module in *Help > About* then *Installation Details* then under *OpenSTM32 Remote debugging support*. To revert to a previous you have two options. If you updated Eclipse then in the *Installation Details* window there is an *Installation History* tab, where you can revert to previous version. Otherwise you should delete the module and search for a previous version in the eclipse install repository.

Comment: Thanks Adam, you were right. Downgrading to C/C++ CDT 9.3 helped solve the problem. I don't understand why such a bug in an IDE has not been solved.

Comment: Mine won't revert because it can't find a plethora of packages. So I uninstalled and installed http://ac6-tools.com/Eclipse-updates/org.openstm32.system-workbench.update-site-st_1.15 (shooting in the dark here). Now I get "An error has occurred. See error log for more details" when I try to do anything with the debugger. Off to figure out where I might find said error log.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the bug report Adam V. mentioned, you can just uncheck Reset & Delay and Halt options in the debugger configuration, and it should work fine.

Comment: this works and is an appropriate solution should be accepted as best response

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when having a breakpoint in a bad place. I got rid of my breakpoints and it solved the "Error in Final Launch" for me. I was then able to set my breakpoints after.

Answer (score 0):

following Setup solved my issue with Eclipse 03-19

- I've unchecked the "Load image" and "Load symbols" check boxes.
- I've removed all breakpoints and after connection was established, recreated them.

Now everything works fine. I've seen, that gdb got's started with sudo (I am using Linux), so perhabs run as admin will be good solution, as well.

[image: uncheck in Startup the "Load image" and "Load symbols" toggle]