# Eclipse "Error in final launch sequence: Command '-file-exec-and-symbols myprog.exe' is timed out

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am using

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>   Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
>   Build id: 20180917-1800

under Win 10 with Portable Msys2, and `gcc 8.3.0`.
When launching a debug configuration in CDT, I am getting message

> `Error in final launch sequence: Command '-file-exec-and-symbols myprog.exe' is timed out`
>
> `Session is terminated`
>   `Reason: Commnd '-gdb-exit' is timed out`

**Note**: *I only get this error while trying to debug one project.
All my other debug configurations for other projects run with no problem.
I have copied one of these working debug configurations and changed only the project name and executable into the problematic one, and I still get the error.*

**One possible solution** I found is ([here](http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread6323#threadId6325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030236/2707864)) downgrading component 
*C/C++ GDB Hardware Debugging* (*Help* -> *About Eclipse IDE* -> *Installation Details* -> *C/C++ GDB Hardware Debugging*)
from 9.4.0.201712051550 to 9.3.2.201709131603.
I have
Version 9.5.3.201809121146 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.feature.group Eclipse CDT.
Perhaps in my case downgarding to that old version would work too.

Prior to messing up with the downgrading, I meant to **try another option** ([here](http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread6323#threadId6525) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392293/2707864)):
In the debug configuration of the project, in the debugger tab, uncheck
“Reset and Delay (seconds)” and
“Halt”.
(more details [here](http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread6323#threadId6391))
But I couldn't find these settings in the *Debugger* tab, and I do not have the *Startup* tab under either the *Debug configuration* for my project or *GDB Hardware Debugging*, as shown [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/jtag-debugging/using-debugger.html) or [here](http://www.ethernut.de/en/tools/eclipse/confdebug.html).
See image.

[image]
**Where can I find these settings?**

**Are there any other alternatives to try solving the issue, other than these two? (lest reinstalling, e.g.)**

**I am looking for something that allows me to debug my project, so far I cannot.**

References I found for similar topics (although not exactly the same) are:

[Error in Final Launch Sequence - Eclipse System Workbench Debugging for STM32L476](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025250/error-in-final-launch-sequence-eclipse-system-workbench-debugging-for-stm32l47)

http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread6323